# Open with Idle not working on python program I have created

Tags: python

Hi I am getting option of 'open with idle' for my python program files. but on clicking it, its not able to open the file. Any guidance will be appreciable. Thanks.

Comment: Are you receiving a specific error message? Your question doesn't have enough information to give you meaningful help.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use IDLE, you can use even built-in Notepad to edit your Python code. Simply use any editor that you feel most comfortable with: Notepad++, Sublime Editor, VS Code, Vim, Emacs or even an IDEs (may be more suitable for a beginner) like PyCharm, Spider.

To run Python prompt (Ctrl+X - type `cmd`): enter `python` and you are in!

To run Python script from a folder (Shift+Right Click in the folder): select `Open Powershell window here`, type `python <script_name>.py`

PS: do not forget to add your Python install to the PATH during the installation, or do it on your own. Otherwise you won't be able to find the actual Python executables.